# UnusedFormalParameter vs. AvoidDuplicateLiterals in maven-pmd-plugin

Tags: maven, pmd

I'm using the built-in rulesets `strings.xml` and `unusedcode.xml` with

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ruleset name="Custom ruleset"
        xmlns="http://pmd.sourceforge.net/ruleset/2.0.0"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://pmd.sourceforge.net/ruleset/2.0.0 http://pmd.sourceforge.net/ruleset_2_0_0.xsd">
    <description>
        The default ruleset
    </description>
    <rule ref="rulesets/java/strings.xml"/>
    <rule ref="rulesets/java/unusedcode.xml"/>
</ruleset>
```

in the `maven-pmd-plugin` as follows:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.8</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>pmd-check</id>
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>check</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <printFailingErrors>true</printFailingErrors>
        <detail>true</detail>
        <rulesets>
            <ruleset>${basedir}/src/main/resources/ruleset.xml</ruleset>
        </rulesets>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

So that I get the following problem in the following use case:

```
public class NewClass {
    private final static String PMD_UNUSED_FORMAL_PARAMETER = "PMD.UnusedFormalParameter";

    @SuppressWarnings(PMD_UNUSED_FORMAL_PARAMETER)
    private void someMethod1(Object parameter1) {
        System.out.println("someMethod1");
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("PMD.UnusedFormalParameter")
    private void someMethod2(Object parameter1) {
        System.out.println("someMethod2");
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("PMD.UnusedFormalParameter")
    private void someMethod3(Object parameter1) {
        System.out.println("someMethod3");
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("PMD.UnusedFormalParameter")
    private void someMethod4(Object parameter1) {
        System.out.println("someMethod4");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        NewClass newClazz = new NewClass();
        newClazz.someMethod1(null);
        newClazz.someMethod2(null);
        newClazz.someMethod3(null);
    }
}
```

Having the annotation parameter value `"PMD.UnusedFormalParameter"` appear 4 times causes an `AvoidDuplicateLiterals` violation. replacing the string with the commented out `private final static` constant causes the annotation to have no effect and thus an `UnusedFormalParameter` violation.

I don't know about the internals of PMD. As an out-of-the-box user it appears  strange that PMD both doesn't substitute the variable with its value (even though that's probably a context sensitive task it should be possible within the scope of static code analysis, it's just complex) and that `UnusedFormalParameter` doesn't exclude string values which are obviously used to suppress other checks and are only there because of PMD.

I'm using `maven-pmd-plugin` 3.8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for your issue, there are currently 2 ways you can work around this:

1. `AvoidDuplicateLiterals` allows for a `skipAnnotations` property that can be set to `true` to ignore literals in annotations. Of course that would ignore all literals in all annotations, not just `@SuppressWarnings`
2. All rules allow you to configure a `violationSuppressXPath` property with an XPath expression of expressions to ignore. For instance, on this case, you can set it to the `AvoidDuplicateLiterals` rule to ignore literals on `@SuppressWarnings`. I believe the proper expression for this would be `//Annotation//Name[@Image = "SuppressWarnings" or @Image = "java.lang.SuppressWarnings"]/..//Literal` (you'd have to test it to make sure)

> I don't know about the internals of PMD. As an out-of-the-box user it appears strange that PMD both doesn't substitute the variable with its value (even though that's probably a context sensitive task it should be possible within the scope of static code analysis, it's just complex)

You are right, this behavior is not currently supported. I've just [added an issue on Github](https://github.com/pmd/pmd/issues/520) to track the request. Feel free to chip in.